# Argument type 'customClass.Type' does not conform to expected type 'NSItemProviderWriting'

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, drag-and-drop

iOS 11.x Swift 4

Trying to implement a custom class for using the new drop and drag protocol and need some super-coder help. I created this class.

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

class CustomClass: NSObject, NSItemProviderWriting, NSItemProviderReading {

var image2D:Data?

static var readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider = [kUTTypeData as String]

static func object(withItemProviderData data: Data, typeIdentifier: String) throws -> Self {
    return try self.init(itemProviderData: data, typeidentifier: kUTTypeData as String)
}

required init(itemProviderData data: Data, typeidentifier: String) throws {
    super.init() 
    image2D = data
}

static var writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider = [kUTTypeData as String]

func loadData(withTypeIdentifier typeIdentifier: String, forItemProviderCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) -> Progress? {
    let data2E = image2D
    completionHandler(data2E, nil)
    return nil
}

}
```

It compiles, looks ok? Then I reference it with this call.

```
func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession) -> [UIDragItem] {
         let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: CustomClass)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        return [dragItem]
    }
```

And I got the error message ... Argument type 'CustomClass.Type' does not conform to expected type 'NSItemProviderWriting'...

But beyond that cannot seem to find any more clues here, there or anywhere as to how to move forward on this.

A side point I implemented one of these guys, it worked...

```
  itemProvider.registerDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeJPEG as String, visibility: .all)
```

And I implemented one of these guys, it worked too...

```
itemProvider.registerFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeJPEG as String, fileOptions: [.openInPlace], visibility: .all)
```

So I am thinking, the code cannot be THAT wrong... surely...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message is correct and your line:

```
let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: customClass)
```

is incorrect for the reason stated. The `object` parameter is expecting an instance of some class that conforms to the `NSItemProviderWriting` protocol. But you are passing in an actual class, not an instance of the class.

Replace `customClass` with an actual instance of your `customClass`. If this method is inside your `customClass`, then pass `self`.

```
let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: self)
```

BTW - this would be less confusing if your followed standard naming conventions. Class and struct names should begin with uppercase letters. Variable and method names start with lowercase letters. So your `customClass` should be named `CustomClass`.

Comment: customClass is a class in the project, but not within the same class as the itemProvider. Will try and adopt your naming conventions too in the meantime!

Comment: If the `dragInteraction` method is not inside your `customClass` implementation then replace `self` with some other variable that references an instance of your class.

Comment: I am not sure I am on the same page; If I need to create an instance of a CustomClass with values, than I'v almost lost all the value in the drop and drag. I need to be able to select the image to drag, not pre-populate it.

Comment: I don't know how your app is setup. But you seem to want to make an instance of your `CustomClass` to be the item provider. So you need to pass in a reference to an existing instance of `CustomClass` when creating the `NSItemProvider`. Where that instance comes from is up to you and your code. But that is what is needed.

Comment: I am having a very similar issue and Xcode tells me that it `Cannot find 'self' in scope`. However I am using it in the class that implements the protocol in question. Any quick ideas?