# Swift 4 Argument type does not conform to expected type 'NSItemProviderWriting'

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4

I am facing this error where I have a structure and I want to make it UIDragItem but I am getting this error

> Argument type 'CustomColor.Type' does not conform to expected type 'NSItemProviderWriting'

I am also adding the type of my Structure

```
struct CustomColor {
    let color : UIColor!
    let name : String!    
}
```

and this function is not working

```
func dragItem(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIDragItem {
    let color = colorDetails[indexPath.row]
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: CustomColor )
    let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
    dragItem.localObject = color
    return dragItem    
}
```

When I am putting CustomColor in side NSItemProvider it's giving me that error. If anyone did solve it or know the solution please help me.

And for reference I saw this answer.
[Argument type 'customClass.Type' does not conform to expected type 'NSItemProviderWriting'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534839/argument-type-customclass-type-does-not-conform-to-expected-type-nsitemprovid)

One request before someone mark it duplicate please do check that we both are facing different issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the instance of **UIColor** not the class of **CustomColor**.

Try whit this:

```
func dragItem(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIDragItem {
   let color = colorDetails[indexPath.row]
   let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: color.color)
   let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
   dragItem.localObject = color
   return dragItem

}
```

Comment: i want to use both the property. color and name ?
what should i do ?

Comment: In that case you need to make a custom class with **NSItemProviderWriting**, **NSItemProviderReading**. This link can help you: [Drag and drop with custom classes using Codable in iOS 11](https://medium.com/@foffer/drag-and-drop-with-custom-classes-using-codable-in-ios-11-77f20fe812eb)