# Swift 4 Implementing drag & drop in collectionView with Cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop

I have custom classes which create an array of objects that are then turned into cells dynamically for my UICollectionView, and the classes all essentially look like this:

```
import Foundation

class BoardNote : NSObject {    
   var note_id : String = ""
   var itemType : String = ""
   var added_by : Any = ""
   var link : Any = ""
   var content : String = ""
   var board_id : Any = ""
   var date_added : Any = ""
 }
```

An instance of this class is then used to create a cell like so:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
"noteViewCell", for: indexPath) as! NoteViewCell
        cell.content.text = (itemArray[indexPath.row] as! 
BoardNote).content
        cell.noteId = (itemArray[indexPath.row] as! BoardNote).note_id
        print("made note cell")
        return cell
```

When I try to implement basic drag & drop in my collection view, I get the error "Could not cast value of type "BoardNote" to 'NSObject'.

I see that I might need to also make this an extension of class NSItemProviderWriting but I am not sure how.

Here is the beginning of my DragDelegate extension where the error is occurring on line 4, which is a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT:

```
extension BoardViewController : UICollectionViewDragDelegate
{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
[UIDragItem]
{
    let item = self.itemArray[indexPath.row]
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: item as! NSObject as! 
NSItemProviderWriting)
    let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
    dragItem.localObject = item
    return [dragItem]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to delete the item cast on this line:

```
NSItemProvider(object: item as! NSObject as! NSItemProviderWriting)
```

Make it just:

```
 NSItemProvider(object: item)
```

Then, the error is self-explained: You need to make you custom class to conform NSItemProviderWriting and NSItemProviderReading protocol, then add the stub methods required from the protocols:

```
class BoardNote : NSItemProviderWriting, NSItemProviderReading{    
   var note_id : String = ""
   var itemType : String = ""
   var added_by : Any = ""
   var link : Any = ""
   var content : String = ""
   var board_id : Any = ""
   var date_added : Any = ""
 }
```

> ***NOTE:*** you can omit NSObject inheritance, [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-NSObject-When-do-Swift-developers-need-to-use-NSObject) is why

You can add protocol stubs simply by clicking  on error red signal then clicking "Fix".

[Here](https://medium.com/@foffer/drag-and-drop-with-custom-classes-using-codable-in-ios-11-77f20fe812eb) a tutorial on how to do Drag and Drop, so you can check how to fill NSItemProviderWriting and NSItemProviderReading protocol stubs.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534839/argument-type-customclass-type-does-not-conform-to-expected-type-nsitemprovid) a similar question you can check

> Basically, the question I linked was asking for a problem in your same line ***NSItemProvider(object: item)***, but the problem was the dev was not giving the method a class instance but the class name

Comment: Hi Andrea, thanks for the help! I've taken your advice & have implemented the things needed to conform as per that tutorial, but I can't seem to overcome the error that my class does not conform to the Decodable and Encodable protocols. Any ideas?

Comment: ^^ I figured it out, that all types needed to conform to primitive types. Still working on implementing the drag/drop, will update soon!

Comment: Hi! So I've implemented everything suggested in that article, and nothing is happening aside from getting a magnifying glass that pops up when I hold down an item and try to drag it. I've got print logs in the drag & drop functions & none are appearing. Should I put my code up in my OG question?

Comment: Have you assigned the delegate ? I forgot to tell you that you have to conform Codable/Decodable protocol too. -> collectionView.dragDelegate = self ; 
        collectionView.dropDelegate = self